# Testing a component with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to Jest and JavaScript in general. I am trying to test my java script code with Jest.

After installing Jest and all the other dependencies around, the initial App.test.js will fail with the message:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
 ● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined

  2 | import logo from './logo.svg';
  3 | import './App.css';
> 4 | import { Grid, Row, Col, Table, Panel, Image, Tabs, Tab, Nav, NavItem, Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
    | ^
  5 | import _ from 'lodash';
  6 | import $ from 'jquery';
  7 | import Request from 'react-http-request';

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-overlays/lib/Transition.js:259:33)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-bootstrap/lib/Collapse.js:41:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-bootstrap/lib/index.js:62:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:3:1)
```

My question is how can I make this test pass?

I know this test should pass successfully when this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.5.1",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.6.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.13",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.5",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^1.2.0",
    "react-http-request": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jest": {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
         "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
         "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
         },
   "resolver": null
  }
```

.babelrc

```
{
 "presets": ["env", "react"] 
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Table, Panel, Image, Tabs, Tab, Nav, NavItem, Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
import _ from 'lodash';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Request from 'react-http-request';
import {AdminViewComponent} from './components/AdminViewComponent.js';
import {WholeScreen} from './components/WholeScreenComponent.js';




class App extends Component { 


  render() {

    var url = "./api/user/" + this.props.userName + "/";
    console.log("props = " + JSON.stringify(this.props));
    console.log("url = " + url);
    var userCompanyIcon;
    //if (this.props.tid == "49d3d3cf-cde6-4161-8d6d-1789042d7b01"){
    if (this.props.tid == "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47" || this.props.tid == "49d3d3cf-cde6-4161-8d6d-1789042d7b01"){
      userCompanyIcon = <Image className="userCompanyIcon" src="microsoftgray.png" responsive/>;
    }


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <Grid>
          <Row>
          <Col xs={6} sm={6} md={6}>                       

          </Col>
          <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={2}>

          </Col>
          <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4}>

            <div className="Hello">Hello, {this.props.fisrtName} </div>                       
          </Col>

          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={4}  sm={4}  md={4}  >
              {userCompanyIcon}
            </Col>
            <Col xs={4}  sm={4}  md={4}  >

            </Col>
            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4}>                       
              <Image className="companyIcon" src="MatanTransperent.png" responsive />              
            </Col>
          </Row>
          </Grid>                    
        </div>   


        <div className="App-content">

         <Request
          url= {url}
          method='get'
          accept='application/json'
          headers={{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.token}}
          verbose={true}>
          {
              ({error, result, loading}) => {
                if (loading) {
                  return <div>loading...</div>;
                } else {
                  if (result == null || result.statusType == 4 ||result.statusType == 5){
                    return <div> an unknown error has occured.  </div>;
                  }
                  else{
                    var returnObject = JSON.parse(result.text);
                    if (returnObject.isAdmin == false){
                      return <WholeScreen data {returnObject.DonationsList}/>;
                    }
                    else if (returnObject.isAdmin == true){
                      return <AdminViewComponent token={this.props.token}/>;

                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            } 
          </Request>-
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you havent added react in the babel env 
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"]
}

Comment: Ok thanks I did what you said but it still does not pass the test. I edited my question so you can see.

Comment: you haven't installed babel-preset-env

Comment: Thanks, well I just did but still not work. Edited my question again so you can see the error. @PatrickHund

Comment: You have a typo in your `.babelrc` file in that you are specifying `presents` instead of `presets`. Hence why you are seeing the `Unknown option` error.

Comment: you can just delete the whole "env": { ... } part, you don't need it

Comment: Sorry for the dumb questions I am totally new into this business. I have edited again my question with the new error. @PatrickHund

Comment: Don't worry, it's fine, we all beginners at some point 

Comment: @PatrickHund Thank you so much. I followed the steps you described in your answer and now when I run the test, it says that there is non - correlation between my svg file and the location of it (if I understood right).

The __mocks__ folder is inside the src and I also created the 2 js files. Edited my question so you can take a look at the error and and package.json   :)

Comment: your path is incorrect, like I said in my answer, the `__mocks__` dir with the two mock modules needs to be in your project root

Comment: And you really shouldn't use absolute paths in the package.json, use the placeholder `<rootDir>`

Comment: @PatrickHund I'm afraid I am not sure about the root. What do you mean by "your project root" ? I opened the     ___mocks___  folder inside the src folder, but the error I that get says:       Could not locate module ./logo.svg mapped as:
    C:/Users/Itay/Documents/Matan - Microsoft/ 
    MatanClient/__mocks__/fileMock.js.    which is weird because I am 100% sure that the folder     __ mocks __  is inside the src folder.  However, if the root that you are talking about is not the src,  I don't have any root folder in my project.

Comment: Project root is the directory where your package.json file is located, not the src directory

Comment: @PatrickHund ok so that's where it was on the first place. I put it back there and the test still fails :( I really can't figure out what else I need to do, edited my question again..

Comment: That seems to be something specific to react-bootstrap now, a Google search for your error message points to this: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2883 – I've never used react-bootstrap, sorry, can't help you.

Comment: @PatrickHund Thank you I learnt a lot from you today!

Comment: Sure, glad to help, good luck! By the way, there is a project called create-react-app that will ease the pain of getting started with React a lot, it has Jest tests and everything set up out of the box: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: Lovely I will give it a try, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is this: You are using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) to be able to import static files, in your case, an SVG image. Jest does not run the JavaScript sources and test files through webpack, only through Babel, which only supports importing JavaScript modules.

The solution how to handle this is explained here in the Jest docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets

You have to tell test: “OK, if you encounter an line where I'm exporting an SVG or other static file, just import a mock JavaScript module instead.”

This is done by adding this to the Jest config in your package.json:

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

…and then you create a directory `__mocks__` in the root of your project and put this file `fileMock.js` in there:

```
// __mocks__/fileMock.js
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

The next issue you'll probably run into will be importing CSS files, which you should handle slightly differently, with a `styleMock`:

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Mock file:

```
// __mocks__/styleMock.js
module.exports = {};
```

Comment: Hi! I would really appreciate your assistance in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53536427/jest-component-testing Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look. How about accepting this answer, if it was useful to you?