# JEST component testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to unit testing with Jest. I am testing a component in a React app. There are two components: `Home` and `LogOutButton`

This is The Home component:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { LogOutButton } from './LogOutButton.js';

class Home extends React.Component {
  displayName = Home.name;

  state = {
    result: 0,
    val1: 0,
    val2: 0,
  };

  handleChangeOne = event => {
    this.setState({ val1: event.target.value });
  };

  handleChangeTwo = event => {
    this.setState({ val2: event.target.value });
  };

  add = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      result: parseInt(this.state.val1) + parseInt(this.state.val2)
    });
  };

  onLogoutClick = () => {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.MICROSOFT.com';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world! The result is: {this.state.result}</h1>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeOne} />
        +
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeTwo} />
        = <br />
        <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
        <br/><br/> 
        <LogOutButton onLogout={this.onLogoutClick} /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Home />, rootElement);
```

`Home` component can get 2 numbers and render their sum. Where it also imports `LogOutButton` Component and when it is clicked, it should redirect you to Microsoft website.

I want to test a scenario where the user click `LogOut`.

This is my suggestion:

```
describe('Home />', () => {
  it('Directing to Microsoft site when LogOut is clicked', () => {
     const homeWrapper = shallow(<Home />);
     homeWrapper.find('LogOutButton').simulate('click');
     homeWrapper.update();
     expect(homeWrapper.html).toEqual('https://www.MICROSOFT.com');
  });
}
```

This does not work..
I am looking for an assistance to write the right test method.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain what "it does not work" means. What is the expected result? What is the actual result? What error message, if any, do you get?

Comment: What you are doing is not best way to go about testing your component.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell how your code will behave without seeing the code for your `LogOutButton` component. But here are a couple of pointers:

First of all, note that your test simulates a `'ckick'` event and not a `click` event as your probably meant.

Second point is that `.html` is a function so you should add parentheses to it in your test: `.html()`.

Third point is that the call to homeWrapper.update() seems redundant.

Lastly and most importantly, even if your component works as intended, the result of clicking the `LogOutButton` would be a page redirect to `https://www.MICROSOFT.com`.

Even if the redirect worked - which I don't think it will, since your test does not run in a real browser - there's no reason to expect that a call to `homeWrapper.html()` would return the URL. It would return the HTML that makes up the rendered component.

In your case, you can expect the call to homeWrapper.html() to return something like:

```
<div><h1>Hello world! The result is: 0</h1><input type=\"text\"/>+<input type=\"text\"/>= <br/><button>Add</button><br/><br/><button id=\"x\">LogOut</button></div>
```

This of course, does not prove that `onLogoutClick` worked correctly. Instead, you might consider replacing `onLogoutClick` with a [Jest Mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) in your test and then expect the mock to have been called once.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for your test is a little addition to what you already have.

```
delete window.location;
window.location = { reload: jest.fn() };

describe('Home', () => {
  it('should click logout button', () => {
    const component = Enzyme.mount(<Home />);
    const logOutButton = component.find(LogOutButton);
    logOutButton.simulate('click');
    expect(window.location.href).toEqual('https://www.MICROSOFT.com');
  });
});
```

You quickly notice I deleted `window.location` as `window.location` is not modifiable in Jest. That is the missing link.